# GraphQL introspection query and generic parser

Tags: rest, parsing, graphql

We wanted to build an application using the GraphQL API and trying to build dynamic discovery where we can query system and get the required objects/metadata (where CRUD can be performed). We know GraphQL provides introspection query, to query the schema. Below are the few query we have identified:

1. `query IntrospectionQuery { __schema { types { name kind ofType { name kind }} } }` - To get all the types. The problem with this query is that it returns all the types (including OBJECT, INPUT_OBJECT, other types). Not all objects are top level. How to differentiate between top level object on which CRUD can be performed.
2. Some endpoint have generic implementation for **Query** and **Mutation**, like a kind of abstract method (Query - businessObjects, Mutation - upsert). How we can derive and map the operations on the object identified above.

We wanted to build a common module which can be applied to any GraphQL endpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain what have you tried so far and where are you stuck , this question does not show or provide details of the research done.

Comment: We wanted to derive something like openapi kind of thing by inferring the schema. But we are unable to do so from the schema. And also observed that every GraphQL endpoint has different way of implementation. Example ->Account(Object Name)->Create, Update, Retrieve and Delete. So when create operation is performed, load the metadata for create operation.

Comment: We have tried query like (get all types, get all queries and mutations)